# How to have TabBarController at the bottom itself on selecting menu Item from the side menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm using SWRevealController to have a side menu. In my app ,it also have UITabBarcontroller.
My connection format is as SWRevealViewController--->UItabbarController--->NavigationController--->UITabbaritemPage-->Another vc

[**PLEASE CLICK ON THE IMAGE TO SEE IN CORRECT ORIENTATION**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KQN1.jpg)

The above show is the layout I'm using.I want to have that burger button (menu button) in almost all vc that are showing from and in tabbarcontroller. Currently I'm getting the side menu when tapping on the Button (The image showed in right side as spereate).On choosing a menu, it shows the desired vc but,the bottom tab bar is not there. I want to have the bottom tabbar in entire pages also in pages from the side menu.

How can I acheive this? Please help me.

**The code I'm using in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is:**

```
if indexPath.row == 1{
let destinationVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
let newFrontVc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:destinationVc!)
revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontVc, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't actually need to push a view controller if using tab bar controller.

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)
```

You would have to set the identifier of the tab bar controller to be `TabBarController` in `Main.storyboard` for this to work.

Comment: No boss.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same layout like you only few view controllers has been added to the tabbar and it will show the tab bar in all view controllers

[image]

Comment: but in this I am facing problem that is when u go by side view controller then the bar button inside the side view controllers is becoming blue and changing whole application back button colours to blue

Comment: dude. Im also in trapp.i will inform once i fixed it :)

Comment: I fixed the back button colours changing @Buddy

Comment: i rebuild everything from scrach...https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/289      ... now i got what i need.Please do refer bro.

Answer (score 0):

## SWRevealViewController with TabBarController using XIB in Swift 4

```
let objSideBarVC = SideBarVC(nibName: "SideBarVC", bundle: nil)
let navSidebar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objSideBarVC)
 navSidebar.navigationBar.isHidden = true

let objDashboardVC = DashboardVC(nibName: "DashboardVC", bundle: nil)
let navDashboard = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objDashboardVC)
navDashboard.navigationBar.isHidden = true

let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController.init(rearViewController: navSidebar,frontViewController: navDashboard)

AppDelegate().window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
mainRevealController.pushFrontViewController(TabBarController, animated: true)
```